# How to Organize Directory Structure for Terraform

Tags: terraform

As a novice, iam trying to set up some structure for terraform projects. We as a team will be using terraform for building infrastructure for Aws ,azure and containers. I will be building infra for dedicated application teams and also cloud services individually.my challenge is set up a consistent directory structure which can be used to build all types of cloud and also for dedicated application  teams. how can i set up a standard directory structure and how can i manage state file for application teams and individually services

THanks for all your knowledge and lessons to me on this

Comment: I'm personally a fan of terragrunt. Here is an example repo layout: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example

Comment: thanks for responding fast. We recently got Terraform as a approved tool in our organisation. now terragrunt can take some time. I will stick with terraform for now but again thanks for replying back. i will check the directory structure in the link

Comment: for me, it works best like -> service as filename. iam resources are in `iam.tf`, ec2 related stuff in `ec2.tf`. for the state file, it depends on the app-teams. i put it in a s3-bucket and have a dynamo-db lock.
also i have different var files like `dev.tfvars` for each workspace, where the variables get filled. `variables.tf` is used fo declaring the vars

Answer (score 0):

I can see one generic and one specific question here!

**Generic Question:** *how can i set up a standard directory structure* (sic)

This purely depends on how your infrastructure is and what cloud services it uses. I would recommend you to start going through this [link](https://www.terraform-best-practices.com/code-structure) to get an idea.

**Specific Question:** *how can i manage state file for application teams and individually services* (sic)

As you might be aware, your state file has the details about your infrastructure's state in its entirety and must be stored safely. Besides, since multiple teams are going to be using the Terraform code to update the infrastructure, do save the state file in an S3 bucket (or equivalent object storage service in a different cloud) and have it fetched every time someone runs `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`. [Reference](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3)

Comment: Thanks Vishwas for the reference. i was able to get some dir structure for my project